# Find numerical value without using a calculator

Tags: algebra-precalculus

4^n+4^n+1/4^n-2

Should I leave it as 4 or change it to 2^2. I'm unable to get rid off all variables.

Please help.

Comment: You mean $\frac{4^n+4^{n+1}}{4^{n-2}}$ ?

Comment: Welcome to Math SE ! Please, at least put parentheses in order what is the formula you nedd to work. Cheers :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you mean: 
\begin{equation}
\frac{4^{n}+4^{n+1}}{4^{n-2}}\nonumber
\end{equation}
If so, then you just have to factor out the expression.
\begin{equation}
\frac{4^{n}+4^{n+1}}{4^{n-2}}=\frac{4^{n}(1+4)}{(4^{n})(4^{-2})}=\frac{5}{4^{-2}}=(5)(4^{2})=80\nonumber
\end{equation}

Answer (score 0):

$4^n + \frac{4^{n+1}}{4^{n-2}}$ ??

if so,

$4^{n+1} = 4*4^n = 4^3*4^{n-2}$ then,

$\frac{4^3*4^{n-2}}{4^{n-2}} = 4^3 = 64$ then,

$4^n + \frac{4^{n+1}}{4^{n-2}} = 4^n + 64$, from there without knowing n, no more simplification may be done

OR,

$\frac{4^n + 4^{n+1}}{4^{n-2}}$ in which case

$= \frac{4^n}{4^{n-2}} + \frac{4^{n+1}}{4^{n-2}} = \frac{4^2*4^{n-2}}{4^{n-2}} + 64$, the second part I solved above

Now $\frac{4^2*4^{n-2}}{4^{n-2}} = 4^2 = 16$

sooo, $\frac{4^n + 4^{n+1}}{4^{n-2}} = 16 + 64 = 80$

Answer (score 0):

We have $\frac{4^n+4^{n+1}}{4^{n-2}}=\frac{4^{n-2}(4^2+4^3)}{4^{n-2}}=4^2+4^3=80$